# Perl functions: Get "name" of incoming parameters

Tags: perl

I'm trying to wrap my head around perl. It's different enough from what I'm used too (.Net mainly, but C/C++/php/javascript) that some things just aren't "grepping" for me.

I'm working through a book that has some exercises. One of the exercises involves practice coercing scalars into Boolean - Undef and Zeros = false, others = true.

Taking the question, some previous code examples and a desire to pull functions out of repeated code... I'm sitting with this function:

```
# Which of the following evaluates to true?

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

sub check1 {
    my @args = @_;
    if ($args[0]) {
        return "true";
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
}

sub check2 {
    my @args = @_;
    if ($args[0]) {
        print "$args[1] = true\n";
    } else {
        print "$args[1] = false\n";
    }
}

# false (zero or undef)
my $def1 = undef;  check2($def1, 'def1');
my $def3 = 0.0;    check2($def3, 'def3');
my $def5 = 0;      check2($def5, 'def5');

# true (not zero and not undef)
my $def2 = ' ';    check2($def2, 'def2');
my $def4 = '0.0';  check2($def4, 'def4');
my $def6 = 'false';check2($def6, 'def6');
my $def7 = 1/0;    check2($def7, 'def7');

#as suggested by TheSuitIsBlackNot
my $foo = 0.0; print '$foo = ', check1($foo), "\n";
```

My question is: Is there a way to remove the duplicate parameter? such that the `check` function can pull the name of the parameter instead of saying `$def1, "def1"`?

Comment: Currently, your function only uses the first argument passed anyway. However, I think it makes more sense to say `0 is false` than `def5 is false`; what is `def5`? The variable name itself has little meaning; the value is what you really care about. If you want to include the variable name in your output, do something like: `my $foo = 0; say '$foo: ', check($foo);`

Comment: Your right. That should have been `print "$args[1] =...` instead of `print "def =...` - updated. Yeah, that does make more sense. Part of it is definitely curiosity though. With .Net, I could delve into reflection to get stuff like parental parameter names (even if it would be what one might call... messy) and was just wondering if the name of the pulling parameter could be called.

Comment: Also, the code this started with was a books question - that got expanded via my curiosity. So `say "0.0 = ", check(0.0);"` or something simple would definitely result in the same output, but I curiosity makes me explore different ways to skin the same cat :)

Comment: `0`, `0.0` and `0.00` are three different ways of writing exactly the same thing

Comment: You certainly *can* do this (see, for example, [`PadWalker`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PadWalker) and [`Data::Dumper::Names`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper::Names), which uses `PadWalker`), but it's ugly, doesn't work for all cases, and generally avoided except for things like debugging. If you need to associate a name with a value in your output, use a data structure like a hash or array as [ikegami demonstrated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29752136/176646). You can also use named parameters in your functions, e.g. `check( name => 'foo', value => 0 );`

Comment: PadWalker won't give you anything you if you do `check($a+$b)`

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, the inputs are from the book I'm poking at. I understand THAT part, just trying to make perl functions work in my mind :)

Comment: `0` and `0.0` are different in C and C++

Comment: Yeah, using the right data structure definitely clicks for me. Odds are, I'd end up using a List of Objects in C#, and placing a name within the object - and Ikegami's answer isn't far from that - not really going for "reflection" to pull the underlying name unless needed. Part of this is more "How" since I haven't really seen "relfection" in perl.

Comment: I don't think you use *grep* correctly in your intro sentence. You are perhaps confusing it with *grok*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution isn't to get the name of the variable; the solution is to eliminate the variable.

```
sub check {
    my ($name, $value, $expected) = @_;
    my $got = $value ? 'true' : 'false';
    print("$name is $got. Expected $expected.\n");
}

my @tests = (
   [ 'def1', undef,   'false' ],
   [ 'def3', 0.0,     'false' ],
   [ 'def5', 0,       'false' ],
   [ 'def2', ' ',     'true'  ],
   [ 'def4', '0.0',   'true'  ],
   [ 'def6', 'false', 'true'  ],
); 

check(@$_) for @tests;
```

Comment: I can see where you are coming from - going from the name being the name of the variable to the name being part of the data structure. Definitely an avenue I hadn't considered.